# Syntax for MySQL INSERT with an array of $_POST variables going into VALUES

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL query construction. I asked a similar question yesterday about columns, and now need help with VALUES. I have a processor for a large form. A few fields are required, most fields are user optional. In my case, the HTML ids and the MySQL column names are identical. I've found tutorials about using arrays to convert $_POST into the fields and values for INSERT INTO, but I can't get them working - after many hours. I've stepped back to make a very simple INSERT using arrays and variables, but I'm still stumped. The following lines work and INSERT the values of 5 variables into a database with over 100 columns. The first 4 items are strings, the 5th item, monthlyRental is an integer.

```
$colsx = array('country', 'stateProvince', 'city3', 'city3Geocode', 'monthlyRental');
$col_string = implode(',', $colsx);
$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($col_string) VALUES ( '$country', '$stateProvince', '$city3', '$city3Geocode', '$monthlyRental')";
```

Following this idea, I use pre-processed variables to construct an array and then implode it to create a string.

```
//these variables are "pre-processed", e.g., $country=$_POST['country'] and validated, but not yet mysql_real_escape_string
$valsx = array( '$country',  '$stateProvince', '$city3', '$city3Geocode', '$monthlyRental' );
$val_string = implode(",", $valsx);
$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($col_string) VALUES ( $val_string )";
```

It does not work. I've tried changing a lot of things, but with no results.  The MySQL error that I get with this code is -  Unknown column '$country' in 'field list'  It is referring to '$country' in the $valsx array, but I don't see how this is a field list, or how to fix the problem.

Please be specific with suggestions. I'm pretty new at MySQL and PHP.

OK, with Iserni's suggestions, here's the current code. It does not execute. I need help with his code, and I need help with where and how to put error messages.

```
$colsx = $fields = $valsx = $values = array();
$colsx = array('country', 'stateProvince', 'city3', 'city3Geocode', 'monthlyRental');
$col_string = implode(',', $colsx);
$valsx = array( "$country",  "$stateProvince", "$city3", "$city3Geocode", "$monthlyRental" );
$val_string = implode(",", $valsx);
foreach($colsx as $col) {
    $fields[] = $col;
    if ( is_numeric($_POST[$col]) ) {
        $values[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col]);
    }else{
        $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col])."'";
    }
}
$fields_sql = implode(',', $fields);
$values_sql = implode(',', $values);
$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields_sql) VALUES ($values_sql);"
if (!mysql_query($query,$conn))
{
    die('<li class=error>an error occurred posting to the database. </li>'. mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Try echoing out your SQL statement, so you can see what you're actually generating.

Comment: Please stop using the old and depreciated `mysql_` statements. Please consider using `PDO` of `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do like this:

```
$colsx = array('country', 'stateProvince', 'city3', 'city3Geocode', 'monthlyRental');
// List of optional fields
$colsy = array('otherfield', 'other2', ...);

// Building the query
$fields = array();
$values = array();

// Mandatory fields
foreach($colsx as $col)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$col]))
        die("MISSING field $col";
    $fields[] = $col;
    if (is_numeric($_POST[$col]))
        $values[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col]);
    else
        $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col])."'";
}

// Optional fields
foreach($colsy as $col)
{
    //if (!isset($_POST[$col]))
    //    die("MISSING field $col";
    $fields[] = $col;
    if (is_numeric($_POST[$col]))
        $values[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col]);
    else
        $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$col])."'";
}

$fields_sql = implode(',', $fields);
$values_sql = implode(',', $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields_sql) VALUES ($values_sql);"
```

If you already have the validated fields, you can do it this way (but then it would be better, as I saw someone suggest, to use PDO instead of mysql_ functions; consider doing this later on).

```
$data = array(
    // FIELD            VALUE ("$country" and $country are the same thing)
    'country'        => $country,
    'stateProvince'  => $stateProvince,
    'city3'          => $city3,
    ...
);

// If you need to add a field conditionally, you do it like this:
// if (isset($_POST['newfield']))
//     $data['newfield'] = $_POST['newfield'];
// or also, maybe:
//
// if (isset($_POST['newfield']) && !empty($_POST['newfield']))
//     $data['newfield'] = $_POST['newfield'];

// Process the values in $data to get SQL fields (PDO does this by itself)

$values = array();
foreach($data as $field => $value)
{
    if (is_numeric($value))
        $values[] = $value;
    else
        $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
}
// Now we have all we need. The "fields" are $data's keys.
$fields_sql = implode(',', array_keys($data));
$values_sql = implode(',', $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields_sql) VALUES ($values_sql);";
```

Same thing using PDO:

```
$data = array(
    // FIELD            VALUE ("$country" and $country are the same thing)
    'country'        => $country,
    'stateProvince'  => $stateProvince,
    'city3'          => $city3,
    ...
);

// Process $data to get SQL fields (we could use array_fill)
$values = array();
foreach($data as $field => $value)
    $values[] = '?'; // Placeholder, without quotes

$fields_pdo = implode(',', array_keys($data));
$values_pdo = implode(',', $data);

// This is now INSERT INTO mytable (city,rent,...) VALUES (?,?,?,...);
$query = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields_sql) VALUES ($values_sql);";

$q = $conn->prepare($query);
$q->execute(array_values($data));
```

Comment: I'll work this tonight - I have an appointment. The PHP already tests for mandatory fields and gives feedback to users before the INSERT. So I think it is just the second bank of code to try out.

Comment: @Iserni I tried the second block of code. It does not execute.  I don't know where to put error messages to find out what's happening. I will try to edit my posting above with the current code so you can see it. The good thing I see in your code is the different treatment of numbers and strings. I have not seen that in tutorials, and appreciate your clarification.

Comment: My code re-extracted the values from _POST, you seem to use $valsx to do so. But in $valsx you do not add quotes around values, and so get an invalid SQL. Will edit answer adding a different approach.

Comment: Iserni, you are a champion. It works. Thank you for being clear and specific, and for your patience to help. I learned from you about strings versus numeric in INSERT, and using associative arrays. I appreciate that you suggested PDO as a next step but worked with me "as is". Learning PDO/mysqli will take a lot of time, but you got me going at the stage I'm at right now.  Thanks, very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your values in quotes - otherwise, SQL will interpret them as field names:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (country)
```

Will look for a column called `country`; whereas

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('country')
```

Will add the string `country`

When your SQL fails, it's always worth printing out to see what's being generated, and running that straight in the database to make sure it actually works - you get error messages that are a lot more helpful, too.

Comment: A string is a type of variable

Answer (score 1):

```
$valsx = array( '$country',  
                '$stateProvince',
                '$city3',
                '$city3Geocode',
                '$monthlyRental'
         );
```

Using single quotes will output the literal characters that are written here. Encasing them with double quotes instead will have them be replaced by the variables content. Or as you have no extra printable characters to add to the string, remove the quotes entirely and use just the variables :

```
$valsx = array( $country,  
                $stateProvince,
                $city3,
                $city3Geocode,
                $monthlyRental
         );
```

**Edit:**

On a side note, it is definitely worth learning to use PDO instead of the deprecated mysql functions. There are some good tutorials around if you google for them.

Comment: I tried removing the single quotes and using just variables, as you show, and I tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes. In both tests, I got an error message - error in syntax at . . .

Comment: Unknown column '$country' in 'field list' ... would indicate you have more literally taken variable names in your code generating your columns

Comment: Sorry, David, I don't understand you and have no idea what to do with your comments. Can you be specific.

Comment: From your initial error, it's clear that $country is being taken literally. i.e. the actual value you are putting into your SQL statement is '$country' rather than it's string representation. Do var_dump($valsx) and see for your self. I think the problem is when you implode the array. Maybe a simple foreach over it would work better.